# Dynamic inline editing with tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to create a table that contains the title and description in which to enter the description, using TinyMCE. I have been successfully using `TinyMCE` for static code html. and TinyMCE show.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$basedomain?>app/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     tinymce.init({
         selector: "div.editor",
         plugins: [
             "table"
         ],
         inline:true,
         toolbar1: "bold italic underline",
         toolbar2: "styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect table",
         menubar: false,
         toolbar_items_size: 'small'
      });
</script>
....
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title[]"/></td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><div class="editor" id="description"></div></td>
</tr>
.....
```

but I want to make the textarea into a dynamic, I've been able to show that area, but `TinyMCE` does not appear.

```
$("img#add").click(function(){
        var html = '<tr>'+
                        '<td>Title</td>'+
                        '<td>'+
                            '<input type="text" name="title[]"/>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td>Description</td>'+
                        '<td>'+
                            '<div class="editor" id="description"></div>'+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
        $('.book_table tr#title').last().after(html);
    });
```

example I have created a form that you can see here
**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfy8zsps/3/)**

Comment: for every click event you are adding same `id="description"` which should be unique

Comment: Can't you run tinymce.init({ selector: "div#description"... after you added the code inside the click event?

Comment: @Riad actual default TinyMCE has give default name that MCE , but you can define the name by using the id. The id later on looping. but the problem I have now is how to TinyMCE can be showing. :(

Comment: Since this is dynamic element...the event is needed to be bind as we do in `jQuery().live()`

Comment: @parthunberg still does not work :(

Comment: @Riad I think there is no problem with it, but it looks like TinyMCE no initial reading of the selector that has been defined. or is there a way to call TinyMCE when on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a day's work, finally I found the solution :D. thanks to  @riad which has helped me a lot. just put :

```
$('.book_table tr#title').last().after(html).ready(function(){
     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, txtAreaId);
});
```

thank you to all of you. you can see the results in here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfy8zsps/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to bind the events for tinymce.

```
$("img#add").click(function(){
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getMilliseconds(); 
 var txtAreaId = "description_"+n;

 var html = '<tr>'+
                        '<td>Title</td>'+
                        '<td>'+
                            '<input type="text" name="title[]"/>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td>Description</td>'+
                        '<td>'+
                            '<div class="editor" id='+txtAreaId+' ></div>'+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>';

  tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, txtAreaId); 

  $('.book_table tr#title').last().after(html);
});
```

Comment: I've tried, but it still does not work. row title and description is showm but not with TinyMCE.

Comment: do you get any error in console... can you put the code in jsfiddle >?